# How to remove the file after restart the Mac machine?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, automation, launchd

I want to remove the specific file (`myfile.jar`) after every restart/power interruption in the Mac machine by automatically. Is there any way available to do this?

My current problem is that my automated code copy the `myfile.jar` from some other folder (`Documents`) to specific folder(`Downloads`). After copied the file this will triggered by `Automator`. The `Automator` code will remove the copied file from that location once it executed. This above process is execute every one minute time period. But If I face any power interruption, This above process will not working as I excepted. If I remove the copied file (`Downloads`), then its working as usual.

How could I do this in Mac?

Comment: You should take a look at `launchd` (see: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html ) - there are also several tools available which provide a GUI, if you are more familiar with this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using `crontab`. Added following code to fix this in `crontab`.

```
* * * * * (sleep 30 && ~/Downloads/myfile.jar)
```